# passing through a filter during the merge (piping?)

Tags: r

I try to merge some data and need to pass through some filter during the process. I have the codes as follow but it keep pop error message. Coundl anyone take a quick look and see what is wrong? I think I wrote it in an incorrect way and I don't know how to correct it.

Many thanks.

```
Summary<-Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Subject", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE),
                   list(`Demographics Merged`[ , c("project","Subject","DMAGE","SEX","RACE","ETHNIC","FEMCBP")],
                        `Cancer History`[ , c("project","Subject","CHCTYP","CHCTYPSP")],
                        `DrugAdminIP` %>% filter(InstanceName %in% c("Day 1", "Day_1"))[ , c("Subject","EXYN","EXDT","EXDSLVL","EXDOSA")]))
```

the error comes from ``DrugAdminIP `%>% filter(InstanceName %in% c("Day 1", "Day_1"))[ , c("Subject","EXYN","EXDT","EXDSLVL","EXDOSA")]))`. I want to merge `"Subject","EXYN","EXDT","EXDSLVL","EXDOSA"` from dataset `DrugAdminIP`, and need to also filter the data with `InstanceName %in% c("Day 1", "Day_1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append the base `[` subset syntax on a piped `filter` call - the order of operations makes it not work. Instead use all base or all `dplyr` syntax:

```
# all base
Summary <- Reduce(
  function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Subject", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE),
  list(
    `Demographics Merged`[ , c("project","Subject","DMAGE","SEX","RACE","ETHNIC","FEMCBP")],
    `Cancer History`[ , c("project","Subject","CHCTYP","CHCTYPSP")],
    `DrugAdminIP`[`DrugAdminIP`$InstanceName %in% c("Day 1", "Day_1"), c("Subject","EXYN","EXDT","EXDSLVL","EXDOSA")]
  )
)

# all dplyr (for the DrugAdminIP)
Summary <- Reduce(
  function(x, y) merge(x, y, by="Subject", all = TRUE, sort = FALSE),
  list(
    `Demographics Merged`[ , c("project","Subject","DMAGE","SEX","RACE","ETHNIC","FEMCBP")],
    `Cancer History`[ , c("project","Subject","CHCTYP","CHCTYPSP")],
    `DrugAdminIP` %>% 
       filter(InstanceName %in% c("Day 1", "Day_1")) %>%   
       select("Subject","EXYN","EXDT","EXDSLVL","EXDOSA")
  )
)
```